# IF-ELSE Formula Field

Tags: formula, formula-field

I want to use formula field, if the InstallDate is blank then formula field should be empty. But when InstallDate is empty formula shows me '--'. Can somebody look at my code? :)

```
IF( Account.Company_Code__c = 'US45' , TEXT(MONTH( InstallDate))+"-" + TEXT(DAY( InstallDate))+"-" + TEXT(YEAR( InstallDate)),

IF( Account.Company_Code__c != 'US45' , TEXT(DAY( InstallDate))+"-" + TEXT(MONTH( InstallDate))+"-" + TEXT(YEAR( InstallDate)),

IF( ISBLANK( InstallDate) , " " ,

NULL )

)

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your formula, you were not checking the null condition for `InstallDate` field and its satisfying any one of the condition(Account.Company_Code__c = 'US45' or Account.Company_Code__c != 'US45') that is the reason you were getting `--` and here `InstallDate` was blank.

try with below formula.

```
    IF( AND(NOT(ISBLANK( InstallDate)),Account.Company_Code__c = 'US45') , TEXT(MONTH( InstallDate))+"-" + TEXT(DAY( InstallDate))+"-" + TEXT(YEAR( InstallDate)),

IF( AND(NOT(ISBLANK( InstallDate)),Account.Company_Code__c != 'US45') , TEXT(DAY( InstallDate))+"-" + TEXT(MONTH( InstallDate))+"-" + TEXT(YEAR( InstallDate)),
""

))
```

The formula checks the if `InstallDate` not blank & Account.Company_Code__c != 'US45' or Account.Company_Code__c = 'US45'

Comment: Thank you! It works! :)